# Where to download Origyn Web Browser for Windows

Tags: windows, browser

I remembered once hearing about some hobby web browser, OWB. Now I really need a low-memory browser for Windows; I tried to download it, but it seems to be decommissioned.

I can't find any place that has archived that binaries. So my question is, maybe somebody else be more successful at finding them ? (At least the win32 binaries.)

Answer (score 1):

For what OS? Amiga? http://strohmayer.org/owb/#Download

Or http://fabportnawak.free.fr/owb/owb-morphos-1.7.lha

or the lite version http://fabportnawak.free.fr/owb/owb-morphos-1.7-nosvg.lha

Comment: No.. I wanted the just the "boring", windows one:)

Comment: I don't think it was ever out for PC - unless you know something?

Comment: Yea, win32 was listed on the downloads page http://web.archive.org/web/20100730213400/http://www.sand-labs.org/owb/downloads

Comment: I have not tested, nor clicked any further on this (since I am at work and don't want to have this in my history with IT) so I can't promise if this is rubbish or not : http://rapidlibrary.com/files/owb-setup-zip_ulzwyrex8fi89on.html

Comment: Not the thing I was looking for, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure it was public though - I agree, I can see a link for it, but there is nothing to say it was live. The reason I say this is, according to wiki it was not made public (although no date is provided) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origyn_Web_Browser)

Comment: I think you need to contact them direct: http://www.sand-labs.org/